# Return Object after INSERT

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am doing a sql INSERT and would like to get a copy of object immediately after insert. Does C# have a command to achieve this??

Comment: There are many technologies within .NET for accessing a database.  Which are you using? Straight ADO.NET, LINQ-to-SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate, something else?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Are you using stored procedure or simply inline sql?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either request the object from the DB immediately after the insert or have it returned directly from the database.

In either case, you will need to write the database query to support it.

Comment: how about having it returned directly from the database? how do I proceed with this option? I am not a DB guru - if u can show me some code..

Comment: @JamaicasFinest - It entirely depends on the database you are using and the data access technology you are using. Both are important details you neglected to mention in your question.